# Autocomplete Tokenfield Bootstrap data not reloading

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tokenfield

I am using autocomplete tags tokenfield from bootstrap. I am having troubles, with the following code I could load the data just the first time I type in the textbox, otherwise, the data isnt reloaded. What am I missing?

```
  var engine = new Bloodhound({
                //local: [{ value: 'red' }, { value: 'red12' }, { value: 'red1' }, { value: 'blue' }, { value: 'green' }, { value: 'yellow' }, { value: 'violet' }, { value: 'brown' }, { value: 'purple' }, { value: 'black' }, { value: 'white' }],
                datumTokenizer: function (d) {
                   return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
                },
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                remote: {
                    url: 'page.aspx/method',
                    ajax: {
                        type: "POST",
                        data: '{ query:"' + $('#cc').val() + '"}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    filter: function (data) {
                        var obj = JSON.parse(data.d);
                        return obj;
                    }
                }
            });
            engine.initialize();

            $('#to').tokenfield({
                typeahead: [null, { source: engine.ttAdapter() }]
            });
```